# Primefaces 5.3 tags not renderded weblogic 12c eclipse

Tags: primefaces, weblogic12c, eclipse-mars

I´ve been strugling a couple of days trying to make work primefaces 5.3 with weblogic 12c deployed with eclipse oepe mars. Our app compile, and run without any problem, but primefaces tags on pages are not rendered, and there´s no one error on console, breakpoints are reached, but no component is rendered
We have tried everything moving primefaces.jar into lib, making primefaces.jar a shared weblogic library. Changing project build path and assembly options and nothing.
We created a small app only with an index.xhtml with primefaces components and no other reference, and it works, other person in my team run that small project on JDeveloper and run smoothly, i would know if there´s anyone else with same problem, and how was solved.

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried using earlier versions of PF (like 5.1) if it would work?

Comment: Yup, and the same(prime 5.3,5.2,5,1,5.0) o one when deployed on eclipse-weblogic works, i came to home and test running the project on netbeans and it works.......... :/

Comment: so this is solved then? maybe it's just a problem with some cached data?

Comment: I dont think, i  installed my stack(primefaces-eclipse-weblogic) on a new envionment in home, create an empty eclipse project, with a new weblogic with nothing, and problems was replicated like in work